# Docusign tabs do not appear on the sent document

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We've added a feature to our app where users can set terms of a loan agreement, and then create a DocuSign contract and send it to the people associated with that deal (brokers, borrowers, etc). Locally, everything works fine, but in production the anchor tabs seem to get lost, because the docs are sent out without any of the tabs applied to them. When a user opens the email they are presented with the "free form" signing mode UI where users can apply any tabs they want, which is the fallback behavior from DocuSign if a document is sent without any tabs. All of the other data(signers, loan terms, company info) is correct and present. When I remote debug prod in Visual Studio, stepping through the flow shows that tabs are created and associated with the correct signers and added to the payload that gets sent to the DocuSign API CreateEnvelope method. Has anyone experienced this before, or know why tabs would get lost in production?

Comment: Can you provide API logs from the DocuSign side? A guide to that is available here: https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Comment: I see from your question that you're using anchor tabs. Check that the anchor text  in the generated documents is really there. For example, take one of the generated docs and send it to yourself. Also, how are you adding the documents to the envelope? Are you doing it at the time the envelope is created, or are you creating the envelope in draft form and then modifying the envelope to add the documents?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but have you tried using `merge_roles_on_draft`? I was able to solve a similar issue using this.

Comment: is this still an issue? is there an API integration involved here?